# Как сделать для админа возможность "войти как {тот или иной user}"

Tags: php, laravel

Есть обычное приложение на Ларавел. Стандартная система аутентификации и авторизации. Но вот потребовалось сделать возможность для админа заходить от имени user. Как можно это правильно реализовать?

Comment: Необходимо написания модуля "подмены данных" в $_SESSION

Comment: Как интересно. Это в какую сторону нужно мне копать? А то что-то туманно пока.

Comment: Ну что то вроде выбираю пользователя под которым хочу зайти, очищаю текущую сессию, а после в сессию забрасываю данные необходимо пользователя(без проверки пароля)

Comment: @Дмитрий, хорошо. Спасибо, подумаю над этим.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HhxJiKjAro ну другие темы в поиске "laravel impersonate users'

Comment: @DmitryKozlov О, вы очень любезны. Спасибо большое!